# Issue related to draggable content in famo.us

Tags: famo.us

I have small application in famo.us framework. There are 5 images. I want drag images. requirement is like when i drag firstImage, second image should be visible behind the first image. i tried to show second image on dragging up of firstImage, but it hides firstimage.

so is it possible to show second image behind the first image ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the z position of your images. Chances are you're encountering z-fighting, where two elements exist on the same position on the same z-axis. Try changing the z-index of the images to different values first to see if that fixes it.

Otherwise, check the 3d-transform you've supplied to famous to make sure your images aren't resting on the same z-value.